# Are similar questions allowed on two sites?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, superuser, scope, serverfault

Are questions which are basically the same sites allowed on on two Stack Exchange sites?

For example take a look at these two questions from Server Fault and Super User.

- **Server Fault** [What is the best way to clean an LCD monitor (display)?](https://serverfault.com/questions/3555/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-an-lcd-monitor-display)
- **Super User** [Cleaning an LCD](https://superuser.com/questions/8254/cleaning-an-lcd)

If yes, then is there a way to link them or for the search box to look across multiple sites?

Comment: What kind of server has a monitor ? =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that the ServerFault question would have been better on SuperUser - if SU had existed at the time. On the other hand, I don't think it's really off-topic on SF.

I think there will always be situations like this - the user groups aren't identical, after all. I think it's okay to have occasional duplication (particularly if there might be a different slant depending on context) but manual linking between posts (i.e. a URL in a comment) is probably good enough.

Comment: Thanks Jon.  Linking them via comments is the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The particular questions you link to don't demonstrate this well, but if they were phrased differently, then certainly they would require a different audience.

For instance, on SF I'd prefer to see:

"We have users across several continents, nations, with different equipment and resources.  We'd like a company-wide policy on cleaning your display devices that will not only work on CRTs, LCDs with glossy finishes, LCDs with matte finishes, conference room TVs, phone displays, etc, but use commonly (and legally!) available, inexpensive solvents and cleaning materials so that we can reduce tech support issues and have a single, cohesive, and widely applicable display cleaning policy."

This would *clearly* be in the realm of IT, whereas the more general "how do I clean my monitor" questions might well be relegated to SU.

Note that the questions are still similar, but they have a different answer and audience, and require a different point of view.